# How do I turn of the 'haze' when highlighting black?

Tags: highlight

I have put this in my `.vimrc`

```
highlight IgnoreGroup ctermbg=Black ctermfg=White
let m = matchadd("IgnoreGroup", '\\todo{.\{-}}')
```

This gives me the following result:

[image]

Note that the `\todo{stuff}` stands out compared to the background.

How can I make it blend with the dark background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The backgroud color is set by the `normal` group.

You could check your colorscheme and use the same colour, which is probably not plain "black".

The `highlight` command can help you observe each highlight. This will show you the settings for the normal group only:

```
:hi normal
```

You could even link your group to the normal group:

```
:hi link IgnoreGroup normal
```

Comment: Using `hi link IgnoreGroup normal` makes it look like normal text and spell check remains activated inside `\todo` which is something I want to avoid. I tried to use the colorscheme idea. I am using `gruvbox` and I looked at `gruvbox.vim` and searched for `background` But I could not see any color assigned to it.

Comment: Finding the background color using `:hi normal` worked. Thanks.